# Aluminum roofing over shingles

Tags: garage, roofing, metal-roof

Can I reroof my garage with aluminum panels, but go over the existing shingles? I’m fairly certain they contain asbestos and don’t want to remove the old.

Surface is plenty flat and planar, and I can get the specialized screws long enough to plant into the decking underneath.

Comment: I have never heard of asbestos shingles for roofing in the US. My parents' owned a house in Louisiana with asbestos siding shingles, but not the roof. Where are you?

Comment: Are you talking about something akin to corrugated metal (exposed fastener) or a standing-seam system (concealed fastener)?

Comment: This question was asked for OSB also I would say the same thing the hard shingles would be better to be removed first. If it is asbestos I would want to know not guess so have it tested as I said with the other question overlay would probably violate building code and punching holes in the rigid tiles will release more asbestos than removing them intact.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Looks like I need to get tested before I move forward.